# In Windows Server 2008 : Powershell can't import-module ActiveDirectory

Tags: windows, powershell, import, active-directory, windows-server-2008-x64

**I am using Windows Server 2008 with a x64 machine and Powershell 3.0.**

After searching for similar problems, I found that I have to install the patches KB969166, KB968934, KB967574, KB968930.

This was done and as a result, the "Web Service Active Directory" appeared in "services".

However, the "ActiveDirectory Module for Windows Powershell" is still not visible in "Windows Features" next to "Active Directory Tools" and "Server for NIS".

**What can I do to make "ActiveDirectory Module for Windows Powershell" entry appear in "Windows Features" ?**

Is it compulsory to have it in there beign checked, as I found here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rkramesh/archive/2012/01/17/how-to-add-active-directory-module-in-powershell-in-windows-7.aspx ?

**Or is there a different way to go so I can have the "ActiveDirectory" module among the list of modules that can be imported in Powershell 3.0 ?**

NB : My ultimate objective is to have the command "`import-module ActiveDirectory`" working in powershell and not resulting in a File Not Found error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PowerShell AD module is only available for Windows Server 2008 R2 and (as part of the RSAT) for Windows 7, not for Windows Server 2008. See [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/2cb1d59c-5a82-493c-9c27-07ab5fe39cfa/installing-active-directory-module-for-powershell-20-on-windows-server-2008-sp2?forum=ITCG) on the Technet forums.

Comment: Available too in Windows 8.1 http://superuser.com/questions/867467/how-to-add-active-directory-module-in-powershell-in-windows-8